# Template Method pattern for static classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

I have a util class that perform some work. Obviously, it is closed for extension and all methods are static. For the sake of simplicity, the class looks like this:

```
public final class Util {
    private Util() { }

    public static void doWork() {
        // some work
        int variable = help();
        // some work uses variable
    }

    private static int help() {
        // some helper functionality
    }
}
```

The class has method `doWork` that performs a lot of calculations. By the way, method calls helper method `help` to obtain some result and rest of the code use the result returned by `help` method.

Now, in client code I want to reuse functionality of method `doWork`, but instead of calling `help` I want to call `help2` method. The simplest solution just create method `doWork2` with replacing `help` to `help2`.

It is very bad approach, because every change in `doWork` must be replicated in `doWork2` either. This very similar to `Template Method` pattern, but due to fact that we don't have extension here, we can't apply it.

Best solution I came up with to add parameter to this method, but preserve all existing users of `doWork`:

```
public static void doWork() {
    doWorkWithParameter(true);
}

public static void doWorkWithParameter(boolean helpOrHelp2) {
    // some work
    int variable = helpOrHelp2 ? help() : help2();
    // some work uses variable
}
```

What are better design solutions can be applied to solve this problem? Is there a way to achieve flexibility like `Template Pattern` has, but in application to util classes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use method overload in your solution?
`public static void doWork() {...}`
`public static void doWork(boolean param) {...}`

Comment: Or better still `public static void doWork(int variable)`.  Though I suspect the actual answer is that the confusion is due to the statics and that objects would provide a cleaner answer - difficult to tell with the abstract examples though.

Comment: What you are looking for is Strategy Pattern. Check Arnaldo's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is inspired in the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), where Util class is a Invoker and each doWork-help pairs are encapsulated using the Worker interface.

The Worker Inteface could be some like

```
public interface Worker {
    public void doWork();
    public int help();
}
```

The Util Class

```
public final class Util {
    private Util() { }

    public static void toWork(Worker worker){
        worker.doWork();
    }

}
```

The Concrete Worker (implementations of help and doWork)

```
public class ConcreteWorker implements Worker{

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int variable = help();

    }

    @Override
    public int help() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Another Worker

```
public class ConcreteWorker2 implements Worker{

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int variable = help();

    }

    @Override
    public int help() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

}
```

And the Execution

```
Util.toWork(new ConcreteWorker());
Util.toWork(new ConcreteWorker2());
```

Comment: Instead of Worker interface you'd better make it as an abstract class with doWork() method. This is actually the same as what I suggest, but just with more code. You have four classes instead of one. I suppose enums are better replacement of static methods.

Comment: Great! It looks like strategy pattern `Collections.sort(lst, Comparator)`. How could I miss that?

Answer (score 1):

You could create 2 static object `Help1` & `Help2` implementing `Help` interface wich have a help() method and change your doWorkWithParameter method like this:

```
public static void doWorkWithParameter(Help h) {
    int variable = h.help();
}
```

It's closely related to your current solution. But I think it's a little more "Object Oriented".

Answer (score 1):

Not so long time ago I have made this:

```
public static enum Helper{
    OLD(){
        public int help(){
            return 0;
        }
    },

    NEW(){
        public int help(){
            return 1;
        }
    };

    public abstract int help();

    public void doWork() {
        int variable = help();
    }
}

public static Helper HELPER = Helper.NEW;
```

then we can call:

```
Constants.HELPER.doWork()
```

By switching HELPER constant values I can change behavior. or you can do:

```
Helper.OLD.doWork();
Helper.NEW.doWork();
```

Comment: This is from Effective Java book - "Item 34: Emulate extensible enums with interfaces"